# Merging Objects with Like Terms

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, functional-programming, javascript-objects

I am currently attempting to group together a data set by various characteristics. I am at the last part of my exercise and that is:

Turn this:

```
[
  {
    "AU": {
      "iOS": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "US": {
      "iOS": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "CA": {
      "iOS": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "US": {
      "Android": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "DO": {
      "Android": 1
    }
  }
]
```

into this:

```
[
  {
    "AU": {
      "iOS": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "US": {
      "iOS": 2,
      "Android": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "CA": {
      "iOS": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "DO": {
      "Android": 1
    }
  }
]
```

In other words, groupBy CountryCode and keep respective iOS or Android tags. Also, keep in mind, no computed keys are allowed. [Computed Keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What if two "iOS" or Android entries exist for the same country? And does the solution have to be based on functional programming?

Comment: The data set prior to this set will have those values accrued and therefore we need not worry about having duplicate sets for this case. Underscore.js is leveraged to groupBy a key, and then groupBy once again by yet a different key. The data is about ready to be stored, it just needs to be organized and this is the last step; to merge based like country codes. functional programming isn't mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In totally vanilla JavaScript -

```
input.forEach(function(item){
    Object.keys(item).forEach(function(country){
        var systems = item[country]
        if (!obj[country]) obj[country] = {}
        Object.keys(systems).forEach(function(system){
            if (!obj[country][system]) obj[country][system] = item[country][system]
            else obj[country][system] += item[country][system]
        })
    })
})
```

If you can use a library (such an Underscore or JQuery) you could tighten up the syntax too

Comment: If that doesn't fall within your limit of not using computed keys but you know what the keys will be in advance, all the easier.

Comment: I much appreciate the help! Nice use of Object.keys as it doesn't iterate over the prototype chain. Thank you! @larz

Answer (score 1):

With a little `omap` helper and `Object.assign` this is a pretty simple task

```js
let input = [
  { "AU": { "iOS": 1 } },
  { "US": { "iOS": 2 } },
  { "CA": { "iOS": 1 } },
  { "US": { "Android": 1 } },
  { "DO": { "Android": 1 } }
]

let omap = (o,f)=>
  Object.keys(o).reduce((acc, k)=>
    Object.assign(acc, { [k]: f(o[k], k, o) }), {})

var output = input.reduce((acc, x) =>
  Object.assign(acc, omap(x, (v, k)=>
    acc[k] === undefined
      ? v
      : Object.assign({}, acc[k], v))), {})

console.log(output)
```

---

**Explanation**

`omap` allows you to map over an object like you can an array

```
let omap = (o,f)=>
  Object.keys(o).reduce((acc, k)=>
    Object.assign(acc, { [k]: f(o[k], k, o) }), {})

omap({a:1, b:2, c:3}, x=> x*x)
//=> {a:1, b:3, c:9}
```

Using `omap`, we can iterate through each of the inputs and map the key to the final output object

```
// reduce the list of inputs by ...
var output = input.reduce((acc, x) =>
  // assigning to the final output, the omap'd input
  Object.assign(acc, omap(x, (v, k)=>
    // if the final output doesn't have a matching key
    acc[k] === undefined
      // return the input's value
      ? v
      // otherwise return the existing final output merged with the input value
      : Object.assign({}, acc[k], v))), {})

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by no computed keys allowed, but I have set up a jsfiddle for this at https://jsfiddle.net/ezrajr/z35q9s3h/

This converts your array of data into an object of data, meaning that you don't have to know the index anymore. You can access the data directly by using string accessor notation:

```
data['US']['iOS'];
```

or dot notation:

```
data.US.iOS;
```

Either one works for accessing data, but typically dot notation is used when you know the key and string notation is used when the key is being set dynamically.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names @Ezra